# Recuperar datos dinámico con JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente `for` que inserta dentro de un modal (después del `box-body`) lo siguiente:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numCa; i++) {
  console.log("indice", i);
  $(".box-body").append('<div class="form-group linea"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="caja ' + i + '" name="caja ' + i + '" value="" required></div></div>');
 }
```

Cuando sale del foco quiero saber el id de dónde se está saliendo pero da `undefined`:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.linea', function() {
    console.log($(this).id);
});
```

¿ Cómo puedo saber el valor y el id correctamente?

Comment: Correcto, quiero saber el id del input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que desea es saber el id del `input` , haga la búsqueda de este de la siguiente forma. `input[type="text"].form-control` buscará los `input` de tipo texto que tengan la clase `form-control` , hay que tener cuidado con esta clase ya que se le añade a la mayoría de componentes de entrada con `bootstrap`. *(puede decidir agrear una clase única para estos componentes y  sería de forma más directa)*

Además como el componente con la clase `.box-body` ya existe en el `DOM` puede utilizar este para escuchar los eventos y reemplazar el `document`.

```js
$('.box-body').on('blur', '.linea', function() {
    console.log("ID " + $(this).find('input[type="text"].form-control').attr('id'));
    console.log("Valor del Input " +$(this).find('input[type="text"].form-control').val());
});

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $(".box-body").append('<div class="form-group linea"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="caja ' + i + '" name="caja ' + i + '" value="" required></div></div>');
}
```

```css
.linea{
  background : #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin :2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box-body">
 
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente, dime para obtener el `value` es cambiado el valor id por value usando la misma salida? Porque ya lo puse y da en blanco
`console.log($(this).find('input[type="text"].form-control').attr('value'));`

Comment: para obtener el valor `$(this).find('input[type="text"].form-control').val()`  se me escapó ese detalle en mi respuesta. ahora la modifico

Comment: Muchas gracias.