# Asignar valor a elemente dinamico jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente `for` donde intento llenar unos input text dinâmicos, la cuestion és que no se como asignar el valor de recorrido del `for` para poder llenarlos correctamente:

```
for (var j = 0; j < respuesta.length; j++) {
         //console.log("indice", i);
          $("caja" + j + ).val(bolsas2[j]); //Obviamente no funciona, necesito asignar en el input text id=caja"x" el valor "x"
 }
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

**EDITADO**

Creo los inputs con el primer for, con el segundo los lleno

```
$(".box-body").html("");
for (var k = 0; k < numCa; k++) {
     console.log("indice", k);
     $(".box-body").append('<div class="form-group linea"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="caja ' + +'" name="caja ' + k + '" value="123" required></div></div>');
}
for (var j = 0; j < respuesta.length; j++) {
     //console.log("indice", i);
      //$("#caja " + j).val(bolsas2[j]);
      console.log($("#caja " + j).val());
      console.log("Bolsas: ", bolsas2[j]);
      console.log($("#cajas " + j).find('input[type="text"].form-control').attr('id'));
}
```

No puedo ver el valor en consola de "123" utilizando esta linea `console.log($("#caja " + j).val());`, siento que no es la forma correcta de atrapar el elemento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo es cuestión de concatenar el valor de la variable iteradora del ciclo `for` con **+**  *(me guié de respuestas anteriores para generar los inputs)*

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $(".box-body").append('<div class="form-group linea"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="caja ' + i + '" name="caja ' + i + '" value="' + i+'" required></div></div>');
}
```

```css
.linea{
  background : #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin :2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
  
</div>
```

Si ya tiene creadas la cajas con un **id** sería cuestión de iterar  e ir asignando el valor de **j** según sea el caso del indice.

```
for (var j = 0; j < respuesta.length; j++) {
  $("#caja" + j ).val(j); // Para asignar el indice del for
  // Para añadir el valor en el indice j del array bolsas2
  $("#caja" + j ).val(bolsas2[j]); 
}
```

Si los `inputs` son creados como en su [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139457/recuperar-datos-din%C3%A1mico-con-jquery/139458#139458) , tiene un error de espacios al momento de asingnar el `id` , `id="caja ' + i + '"`
debería ser sin el espacio `id="caja' + i + '"`

Comment: El problema es que los "inputs" ya estan creados, solo necesito acceder a su id (que el mismo posee un numero despues del nombre como "caja2" o "caja1000") y llenarlos.

Comment: Intente con esto que me parece es la solución y aún nada `$("#caja" + j ).val(bolsas2[j]);`, afecta en algo que el `<div class="form-group linea">... input bla bla </div>` haya sido creado dinamicamente con el `.append()`?
Gracias.

Comment: @Baker1562 los inputs son los mismos que los de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139457/recuperar-datos-din%C3%A1mico-con-jquery/139458#139458)?  ¿Qué tiene bolsas2?

Comment: Correcto., el problema es que hay por ejemplo 10 inputs pero en ese modal con esos 10 inputs solo tengo 2 o 3 datos (no todos) por eso no podia asignar los datos de una vez sino hasta despues que los inputs fueran creados.

Comment: @Baker1562 al final de mi respuesta noté un espacio de más al momento de asignar el ID ,revise ese detalle puede ser que sea este el detalle que falta.

Comment: Para ver si lo podia accesar o no, a los input que cree (10 digamos) les asigne el valor de "123" cuando cargo el modal obviamente los inputs tienen ese valor pero cuando quiero lanzar en un for usando la siguiente linea: `console.log($("#caja " + j).val());` me lanza `undefined`, siento que no estoy llamando correctamente el valor para recuperalo ni para establecerlo, edito la pregunta para mostrar como los creo

Comment: @Baker1562 no debe haber espacios en el id , usted está añadiendo espacios, mire la última parte de mi respuesta , es decir  `$("#cajas" + j).val(j);`  notese que no tiene espacios después de cajas

Comment: Listo, mi error, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tu único error era que te sobraba un **+** en tu selector y te faltaba agregar el indicativo del elemento ya sea un **#** para indicar que quieres seleccionar por medio del atributo `id` o un **.** para indicar que quieres seleccionar por medio del atributo `class`

```js
var bolsas2 = ['valor 1', 'valor 2', 'valor 3']

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    $("#caja" + j).val(bolsas2[j]);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="caja0" type="text">
<input id="caja1" type="text">
<input id="caja2" type="text">
```